# Specifying variable size when passing one to the cursor in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

If I define the cursor that accepts 2 parameters like this:

```
CURSOR cur_det (var1 IN varchar2,var2 IN varchar2)  IS
```

Is it possible to specify their size? thanks

Comment: Have you tried `CURSOR cur_det (var1 IN varchar2(10),var2 IN varchar2(72))  IS... ` to see what happens?

Comment: @Frustrated - You get ORA-06550, PLS-00103, " Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting...". It doesn't like the "(10)".

Comment: @redcayuga: I was trying to suggest to the OP that they should try it themselves and report the results before just asking here.

Comment: @Frustrated: I see your point, this is an RTM question. Is there an acronym for "Try It Yourself So You Don't Have To Ask" - TIYSYDHTA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot specify `varchar2(100)` or something similar. The varchar being passed is not constrained.

You can use the %Type to anchor the parameter to a database column, i.e., `my_table.a_column%Type`. But I don't think that actually constrains the parameter.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. My issue is elsewhere upon closer inspection, but this is useful. thanks